# CARET. Relationship between data splitting and trainControl

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation

I have carefully read the [CARET](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/index.html) documentation at: http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/training.html, the vignettes, and everything is quite clear (the examples on the website help a lot!), but I am still a confused about the relationship between two arguments to `trainControl`:

```
method 
index
```

and the interplay between `trainControl` and the data splitting functions in caret (e.g. `createDataPartition`, `createResample`, `createFolds` and `createMultiFolds`)

To better frame my questions, let me use the following example from  the documentation:

```
data(BloodBrain)
set.seed(1)
tmp <- createDataPartition(logBBB,p = .8, times = 100)
trControl = trainControl(method = "LGOCV", index = tmp)
ctreeFit <- train(bbbDescr, logBBB, "ctree",trControl=trControl)
```

My questions are:

1. If I use `createDataPartition` (which I assume that does stratified bootstrapping), as in the above example, and I pass the result as `index` to `trainControl` do I need to use `LGOCV` as the method in my call `trainControl`? If I use another one (e.g. `cv`) What difference would it make? In my head, once you fix `index`, you are essentially choosing  the type of cross-validation, so I am not sure what role `method` plays if you use `index`.
2. What is the difference between `createDataPartition` and `createResample`? Is it that `createDataPartition` does stratified bootstrapping, while `createResample` doesn't?

3) How can I do **stratified** k-fold (e.g. 10 fold) cross validation using caret? Would the following do it?

```
tmp <- createFolds(logBBB, k=10, list=TRUE,  times = 100)
trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", index = tmp)
ctreeFit <- train(bbbDescr, logBBB, "ctree",trControl=trControl)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure what role method plays if you use index, why not to apply all the methods and compare results. It is a blind method of comparaison, but it can give you some intuitions.

```
  methods <- c('boot', 'boot632', 'cv', 
               'repeatedcv', 'LOOCV', 'LGOCV')
```

I create my index:

```
  n <- 100
  tmp <- createDataPartition(logBBB,p = .8, times = n)
```

I apply `trainControl` for my list of method, and I remove index from result since it is common to all my methods.

```
ll <- lapply(methods,function(x)
         trControl = trainControl(method = x, index = tmp))
ll <- sapply(ll,'[<-','index', NULL)
```

Hence my ll is :

```
                 [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]         [,5]      [,6]     
method            "boot"    "boot632" "cv"      "repeatedcv" "LOOCV"   "LGOCV"  
number            25        25        10        10           25        25       
repeats           25        25        1         1            25        25       
verboseIter       FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE        FALSE     FALSE    
returnData        TRUE      TRUE      TRUE      TRUE         TRUE      TRUE     
returnResamp      "final"   "final"   "final"   "final"      "final"   "final"  
savePredictions   FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE        FALSE     FALSE    
p                 0.75      0.75      0.75      0.75         0.75      0.75     
classProbs        FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE        FALSE     FALSE    
summaryFunction   ?         ?         ?         ?            ?         ?        
selectionFunction "best"    "best"    "best"    "best"       "best"    "best"   
preProcOptions    List,3    List,3    List,3    List,3       List,3    List,3   
custom            NULL      NULL      NULL      NULL         NULL      NULL     
timingSamps       0         0         0         0            0         0        
predictionBounds  Logical,2 Logical,2 Logical,2 Logical,2    Logical,2 Logical,2
```

Comment: Interesting. Thanks! I am having a hard time mapping your answer to my questions. Based on this, what role do you think  `index` played here then?

Comment: @user273158 what  do you mean the role of index? index is just you tmp vector...your partitions..

Comment: Hmm, but how does a method like `boot` (bootstrapping) use the partitions specified in `index`? I understand bootstrapping as a method for CV (sample with replacement to train, and evaluate on what's left), but not how `index` is used in bootstrapping.

Comment: @user273158 yes I know. I am not sure ...but I think that your guess is correct., once you fix the index , you are doing a sort of presampling (offline) and with method it is online sampling....I am verifying something and I will post my final answer after...