# PreProcessing Scale for predict in R - Not getting same scale for predict

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, r-caret

I am training a neural network in R using the train function in the caret package. I am using some example code found here:[Time-series - data spliting and model evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24758218/time-series-data-spliting-and-model-evaluation?noredirect=1&lq=1).

The output of the network training tells me that it has been re-scaled to [0,1] but when I used the predict function, my predictions are not scaled to [0,1]. First, how do I know if the data has been normalized properly? And second, how do I get the normalized predictions?

Here is my code:

```
timeSlices <- createTimeSlices(1:nrow(mytsframe3), initialWindow = 36,
                           horizon = 12, fixedWindow = TRUE)

nn <- train(diffREALBRENTSPOT ~ diffF1REALlag + diffF2REALlag, data = mytsframe3[trainSlices[[1]],], method = "mlp"
        , size = 1, preProc = c("range"))

> nn
Multi-Layer Perceptron 

36 samples
 2 predictor

Pre-processing: re-scaling to [0, 1] (2) 
Resampling: Bootstrapped (25 reps) 
Summary of sample sizes: 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  size  RMSE       Rsquared 
  1     0.7879697  0.2098693
  3     0.7485212  0.2249331
  5     0.7571630  0.2246444

RMSE was used to select the optimal model using  the smallest value.
The final value used for the model was size = 3. 

pred <- predict(nn, mytsframe3[testSlices[[1]],])

str(pred)
 Named num [1:12] 0.0734 -0.0214 0.3264 0.0362 -0.1569 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:12] "37" "38" "39" "40" ...
```

Here is a `dput` of my data for testing:

```
structure(list(diffREALBRENTSPOT = c(-0.523999999999999, -0.693, 
0.386999999999999, 0.453000000000001, -0.842000000000001, 0.369999999999999
), diffF1REALlag = c(0.48597655, -1.61485375, 0.60622805, -0.469351210000001, 
0.292303670000001, -0.44088176), diffF2REALlag = c(1.00948236, 
0.48597655, -1.61485375, 0.60622805, -0.469351210000001, 0.292303670000001
)), .Names = c("diffREALBRENTSPOT", "diffF1REALlag", "diffF2REALlag"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Maybe `predict` defaults to giving you log-odds, and you need to transform them to 0-1? Did you try including `type = "response"` in the call to `predict`?

Comment: @ulfelder including `type = "response"` produces an error of the form: `Error in predict.train(nn, mytsframe3[testSlices[[1]], ], type = "response") : 
  type must be either "raw" or "prob"`

Comment: Well, then, did you try `type = "prob"`?

Comment: @ulfelder, using `type = "prob"` produces `data frame with 0 columns and 12 rows` where the rows are just the row numbers of the timeslices

Comment: Can you post data to allow us to replicate your results and test fixes?

Comment: @ulfelder I just made an edit, adding some data so you can replicate.  You'll need to adjust some of the parameters in create time slices, and the RMSE's wont be the same.

Answer (score 2):

> The output of the network training tells me that it has been re-scaled to [0,1] but when I used the predict function, my predictions are not scaled to [0,1].

The outcome is numeric and you are fitting a regression model (not classification). The `preProc` option rescales your *predictors* to be on [0,1] and does not rescale the outcome or the predictions to be on this range.