# Caret package - Is it possible to use the package in R without resampling?

Tags: r, neural-network, r-caret

I'm starting to use the caret package.

My study is about a prediction of historical financial series. I have a training period of 6 years for the input of a neural network. It is important that the input data follow the historical sequence.

I would like to use the `caret` package without sampling, but with all the historical information.

I think that by default the function does sampling. I only saw options to change shape of sampling in function `trControl()`.

My tuning would be the number of neurons and what input variables are best. I would like to change an activation function too.

Is it possible?

```
m  <- train(Sepal.Length~.,
        data = iris, 
        method = 'mlpWeightDecay', 
        metric = 'RMSE',
        maxit=100,
        tuneGrid = expand.grid(size=1:2, decay=1)
)
```

Comment: You want the `method=timeslice` option to `trControl()`. See `?trainControl` and https://topepo.github.io/caret/data-splitting.html#data-splitting-for-time-series

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time-series - data splitting and model evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24758218/time-series-data-splitting-and-model-evaluation)

Comment: @JohnColby thanks for the answer. Do you also know if it is possible to change the activation function?

Comment: I tried with example economics (Time-series - data splitting and model evaluation), plsFitTime <- train(unemploy ~ pce + pop + psavert,
+                     data = economics,
+                     method = "mlpWeightDecay",
+                     preProc = c("center", "scale"),
+                     trControl = myTimeControl) the answer: Warning message:
In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.