# splitting data for time series prediction

Tags: r, time-series, r-caret

I am looking for an R package, which allows me to do n-fold CV type hyper parameter optimisation (e.g. n = 10). Let us say this is the data I can used to tweak the hyper parameters (I tend to use rBayesianOptimization so let us abstract this away):

```
dates <- seq(as.Date('2017-01-01'), as.Date('2019-12-31'), by = 'days')

df <- data.frame(date = dates)
df$y <- 42
```

Here y, the dependent variable, is an obviously well known constant and it is just added here without being exploited.

I came across the caret function [createTimeSlices](https://topepo.github.io/caret/data-splitting.html) and this would be a possible approach to split the data:

```
slices <- createTimeSlices(df$date, initialWindow = 365 * 2.5, horizon = 30, fixedWindow = TRUE)
```

I end up with a list like this:

```
List of 2
 $ train:List of 153
  ..$ Training0912.5: int [1:912] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  ..$ Training0913.5: int [1:912] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ...
...   
  ..$ Training1010.5: int [1:912] 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 ...
  .. [list output truncated]
 $ test :List of 153
  ..$ Testing0912.5: num [1:30] 914 914 916 916 918 ...
  ..$ Testing0913.5: num [1:30] 914 916 916 918 918 ...
```

Can someone please point pout how to use this or refer me to another package? Personally, I am a bit confused about the training data indices only to shift 1 day (?). I would have thought it shifts 30 days (see horizon).

Thanks.

Comment: What is your specific goal?  You mention 10-fold CV, parameter tuning, and data segmentation, and also a question about how to use the `createTimeSlices` function.  If you can provide exact expected output, and clarify what your question is, that'd be helpful.

Comment: It is a bit hard to provide an example in this casa imho. In 10 fold CV you use 9 folds for training and 1 for validation. You get 10 performance measures e.g. the AUC. You can then calculate the average for the hyper parameter setting. I want to do something similar for time series. Obviously, time series are sequential but the principle is the same.

Comment: You might want to check out packages fable & fabletools and modeltime. They deal with timeseries and forecasting.

Comment: Thanks will have a look.

Comment: @phiver these package look interesting. If you could be so kind an point me to the doc/code to show how to split a ts that would be very kind. As so often the doc looks sketchy ...

Comment: @cs0815, the [must read book](https://otexts.com/fpp3/) for fable & fabletools and forecasting in general.  For modeltime: https://www.business-science.io/code-tools/2020/06/29/introducing-modeltime.html modeltime.ensemble: https://www.business-science.io/code-tools/2020/10/13/introducing-modeltime-ensemble.html modeltime.resample: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/modeltime.resample/vignettes/getting-started.html

Comment: I was aware of the must read book thanks. In the meantime I found a way to use createTimeSlices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to use createTimeSlices inspired by [Shambho's SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24758218/time-series-data-splitting-and-model-evaluation).

```
library(caret)

dates <- seq(as.Date('2017-01-01'), as.Date('2019-12-31'), by = 'days')

df <- data.frame(date = dates)
df$x <- 1
df$y <- 42

timeSlices <- createTimeSlices(1:nrow(df), initialWindow = 365 * 2, horizon = 30, fixedWindow = TRUE, skip = 30)

#str(timeSlices, max.level = 1)

trainSlices <- timeSlices[[1]]
testSlices <- timeSlices[[2]]

for (i in 1:length(trainSlices)) {

    train <- df[trainSlices[[i]],]
    test <- df[testSlices[[i]],]

    # fit and calculate performance on test to ultimately get average etc.

    print(paste0(min(train$date), " - ", max(train$date)))
    print(paste0(min(test$date), " - ", max(test$date)))
    print("")
}
```

The key for me was to specify skip as otherwise the window would only move 1 day and one would end up with to many "folds".